# Trouble converting function to square color

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

I think I have got down the basics of the programming language Swift, so now I have been trying to take it a little further. Earlier today, I read a question about how to generate a random color, so I tried to use that function to color in my blank square (UIView).

```
import UIKit

func generateColors() -> (main: UIColor, diff: UIColor) {

    let redMain: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(104))
    let greenMain: CGFloat = redMain + 105.0
    let blueMain: CGFloat = redMain + 83.0

    let redColorMain: CGFloat = redMain / 255.0
    let greenColorMain: CGFloat = greenMain / 255.0
    let blueColorMain: CGFloat = blueMain / 255.0
    let main = UIColor(red: redColorMain, green: greenColorMain, blue: blueColorMain, alpha: 0.8)

    let redDiff: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(104))
    let greenDiff: CGFloat = redDiff + 105.0
    let blueDiff: CGFloat = redDiff + 83.0

    let redColorDiff: CGFloat = redDiff / 255.0
    let greenColorDiff: CGFloat = greenDiff / 255.0
    let blueColorDiff: CGFloat = blueDiff / 255.0
    let diff = UIColor(red: redColorDiff, green: greenColorDiff, blue: blueColorDiff, alpha: 0.8)

    return (main, diff)
}

var square: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
square.backgroundColor = generateColors()
```

I have tried many things, and I think it seems to be the parameter in the function at the end. Do I have to call on either main or diff a specific way, for a tried the obvious.

Comment: Did you notice that `generateColors()` creates and returns *two* colors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Swift but [a cursory look at `UIView` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/backgroundColor) suggests that `backgroundColor` is just one color, not a pair, unless there's some language thing I don't know about. So instead of a pair try:

```
return main;
```

Or:

```
return diff;
```

And change your function return type to a single color, whatever the syntax for that is (which I'm presuming is `func generateColors() -> UIColor {`).

Hope that helps...